# The reason why dataset does not create layer

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, ogr, spatialite

I have a plugin written in Python, and two versions of the QGIS, assembly there are differences, but the main suspect, that the version of GDAL==2.0.0dev (1) another 1.11.3 (2)

for first

```
>>>from osgeo import ogr, osr
>>>path_to_db = 'some/path'
>>>ds = drv.Open(path_to_db, True)
>>>ds
<osgeo.ogr.DataSource; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRDataSourceShadow *' at 0x000000001AAD09C0> >
>>>srs = osr.SpatialReference()
>>>srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
0
>>>layer = ds.CreateLayer('foo', srs, ogr.wkbMultiLineString)
>>>layer
>>>type(layer)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

for second

```
    >>>from osgeo import ogr, osr
    >>>path_to_db = 'some/path'
    >>>ds = drv.Open(path_to_db, True)
    >>>ds
    <osgeo.ogr.DataSource; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRDataSourceShadow *' at 0x000000001AAD09C0> >
    >>>srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    >>>srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    0
    >>>layer = ds.CreateLayer('foo', srs, ogr.wkbMultiLineString)
    >>>layer
    <osgeo.ogr.Layer; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRLayerShadow *' at 0x000000001AAD0DB0> >
```

How to know what went wrong?
No exceptions.
How to fix this?

---

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas

ogr.UseExceptions()
helped me! little **BUT**

RuntimeError: Data source C:\Users\path/database.sqlite opened read-only.
New layer foofooo cannot be created.

but why it opened read-only?!))

Comment: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas

Comment: If you use QGIS, why not use PyQGIS instead of osgeo ?

Comment: There are several instances where read-only mode is enforced for the [SQLite driver](http://gdal.org/drv_sqlite.html), you should provide more details on how you installed the versions of GDAL, and on what platform.

Comment: Is it possible create dataset using PyQGIS? In tutorial http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html they use existance database, but i want to create new spatial lite.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with osgeo

```
ds = ogr.Open('a_shapefile.shp')
# or
ds = ogr.Open('a_shapefile.shp',0)
```

none or 0 means read-only.

```
ds = ogr.Open('a_shapefile.shp',1)
```

1 means writeable.

Comment: I have used this flag. I used and 1 and True - does not help.